# BootStrap DatePicker NoConflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

According to the document: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#no-conflict

bootstrap datepicker can use noConflict now:

```
var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
$.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;    // give $().bootstrapDP the bootstrap-datepicker functionality
```

It said "give $().bootstrapDP the bootstrap-datepicker functionality", what does this mean? Does it means I can use `$("#object").bootstrapDP()` instead of `$("#object").datepicker()`?

I have tried it in firefox (just for test, actually not conflict to any js), but  the "date-choose" does not show, and no error appear (from firebug), that is weird.

Below is my code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text"  readonly><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict;
    $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;  
    $("#dp3").bootstrapDP();    
  });
</script>
```

When I replace the script with `$("#dp3").datepicker()`, the "date-choose" will show.
Can anyone tell me how to use noConflict to bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: Is that your actual script? Coz you're missing a `()` on `.noConflict`. Anyhow, your issue would be easier to solve if you posted a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the suggestion. Can I ask why there is no error showing in the firebug console (firefox) or IE when I miss the paren?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You missed the parens on the `noConflict` function.

Code:

```
$(function(){
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;  
    $("#dp3").bootstrapDP();    
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/faxyz/

Comment: Can I ask why there is no error showing in the firebug console (firefox) or IE when I miss the paren?

Comment: @morgan117: It's because functions in javascript work as objects. There's nothing syntactically incorrect with assigning `noConflict` to a variable. It's no different than saying `var datepicker = function() {}`. Your call to `.bootstrapDP()` ended up just calling `noConflict()`, which doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: Who says this is a valid answer @Irvin
Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.datepicker.noConflict is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:34
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)

Comment: @Kannu it can be a different situation, I think is better if you ask another question

Comment: @IrvinDominin, also in the jsFiddle example. There is no jquery UI included at all..... huh

Comment: @Kannu is not jQuery UI, is bootstrap; bootstrap noconflict is included in the script section because at the post date any cdn serve it

Comment: I still got the same error even with the demo code. So I ended up just using the JQuery UI builder http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4 and just removed the 'datepicker' module since I don't use it. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who wasn't helped by the accepted answer (like me) see below...

Rather than use the jQuery initialization, utilize the `data-api` instantiation like so:

`<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" />`

This allows you to use the Bootstrap datepicker, without worrying about conflicting with jQuery UI's datepicker.

Comment: I need to login and vote for this guy. Thank you for saving my day

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using everything from Jquery UI you can customize the widgets which you want from Jquery UI.

In this case, you can remove jquery datepicker and build new files and use them.

Use this jquery ui widget builder: https://jqueryui.com/download/