# The Conflict of BootStrap and jQuery-UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

My original web page is using Bootstrap datepicker.
However, for adding an existing old date-picker with jQuery-UI, I need to make these two coexist.

I already read the articles in [BootStrap DatePicker NoConflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507908/bootstrap-datepicker-noconflict) and [jQuery ui datepicker conflict with bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277563/jquery-ui-datepicker-conflict-with-bootstrap-datepicker).

My coding logic is:

Step 1: Load jquery-ui.custom.min.js before bootstrap-datepicker.js, bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap-datepicker.js, and bootstrap-select.js.

Step 2: Add the following scripts:

```
  if (!$.fn.bootstrapDP && $.fn.datepicker && $.fn.datepicker.noConflict) 
  {
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;
  }

  $(".DatePickerForjQuery-UI").datepicker({});
  $(".DatePickerForBootStrap").bootstrapDP({});
```

Step 3: Set up each's datepicker parameters

```
$(".DatePickerForjQuery-UI").datepicker({.........});
$(".DatePickerForBootStrap").datepicker({.........});
```

The result is: `$(".DatePickerForjQuery-UI")` works good, but `$(".DatePickerForBootStrap")` will show Bootstrap and jQueryUI date-picker **at the same time** when I click it.....

Have any ideas why `$(".DatePickerForBootStrap")` doesn't show correctly?

Answer (score 2):

In case of conflict between jQuery and bootstarp datepicker you can open your jQuery-ui.js and rename the datepicker() function to datepickerj() or by any other name. Now they are two different method . Can use them by different way without  any conflict and without any distortion due to conflicting css class

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer.

In step 3, if we need to use Bootstrap date-picker, the syntax is:

```
 $(".DatePickerForBootStrap").bootstrapDP({.........});
```

Since we already update/give the new definition of Bootstrap in Step 2.
So, all the related Bootstrap date-picker functions will always use "**bootstrapDP**" to work.
Like,

```
         $('.datepicker-textbox')
          .bootstrapDP({
               update: $(this).val(),
               startDate: '<%= DatePickerStartDate %>',
               format: '<%= DateFormatClientSide %>'
            })
            .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).bootstrapDP('hide')
            })
            .on('hide', function (ev) {
                $(this).removeClass('opened');
            });
```

Comment: This saved my day. Thanks for the wonderful solution @user3174976.