# BootStrap DatePicker NoConflict - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I've followed the instruction how to disable the jquery-UI datepicker and using the bootstrap datepicker [BootStrap DatePicker NoConflit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507908/bootstrap-datepicker-noconflict) but I get this error message in browser :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.datepicker.noConflict is not a function
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text"  readonly>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapDP = datepicker;  
    $("#dp3").bootstrapDP();     
 });
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not loading a library. What does your Head look like?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and jquery-ui in a RAILS 6 application. And load both modules via the yarn package manager. I'm using features from both modules in my application without issues, so it seems to be loaded in the correct manner.